# How to add embedded links to html 5 videos

Tags: html, video

If you link a YouTube video in Discord it gets shown as a player-able video on discord and not just a link. With my videos if i link them from my website discord shows them as a link and not a video. I heard i need to have embedded links in it but i don't know what I'm looking for or how to make or add those in. Anyone able to help me? Here is my current code for my videos:

```html
<video poster="Images/logo.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
            <source src="videos/logo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

Comment: what is the exact code that you post on Discord that should link your video?

Comment: This is my video from my website and this is the code i post in discord to link a video but the video doesnt show up as a video just a link. https://thg-graphics.com/videos/THG-Green.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just post a youtube url like that

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNpczxZLXo8

in the chat on https://discordapp.com/. Some time later, the chat window comes up with the embedded video from youtube.

This means they have special support for youtube links and as far as they do not explicitly provide a way to do the same for other websites, you do not have any chance to recreate the same functionality.

The options i see for you are: talk to support from discordapp.com or upload your stuff to youtube.

[Edit]
After contacting support, we know now that they actually do explicitly support 3rdparties to embed videos and images.

The answer from https://discordapp.com/ support came quick and spot on:

**We look for Facebook open graph tags, Twitter's card tags, or oembed more information:**

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

**Facebook Opengraph Example:**

Code of opengraph2.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <meta property="og:type" content="article">
       <meta property="og:url" content="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/index.jsp">
       <meta property="fb:app_id" content="217926898242066">
       <meta property="og:video" content="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.m4v" />
       <meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
       <meta property="og:video:height" content="426" />
       <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/mp4" />
       <meta property="og:video" content="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.m4v" />
       <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
       <meta property="og:video" content="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.m4v" />
       <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
       <meta property="og:title" content="title text">
       <meta property="og:image" content="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.png"/>
       <meta property="og:description"  content="description text"/>
       <meta property="og:site_name" content="site name text">
       
       <body>
       
       
       <style type="text/css">
       
       video {
       
          width:100%;
       
          max-width:600px;
       
          height:auto;
       
       }
       
       </style>
       
       
       <video width="100%" src="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.m4v" controls>
       
        Your browser does not support video
       
       </video>
       
       
       </body>
       
       </html>
```

- https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup

**Twitter Example**:

Code of twitter.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="player" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@harry" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="CUSTOM CONTENT" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Custom Descriptions can be lengthy" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png?x11217" />
    <meta name="twitter:player" content="https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" />
    <meta name="twitter:player:width" content="320" />
    <meta name="twitter:player:height" content="180" />
    <meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" />
    <meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="video/mp4" />
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
video {
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   height:auto;
}
</style>
<body>
<video width="100%" controls>
  <source src="http://harry.x-dream-media.com/test.m4v" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support video
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

- http://oembed.com/#section2

Comment: Ok thanks man. Yeah i dont wanna upload my work to youtube. Makes it easier to steal my work..... Where atm i can block right click and a ton of other nifty things to help prevent someone from easily gaining access to download my stuff.... Though i am still considering the idea of using youtube.

Comment: I like that you produce your own content and understand your concerns. If you like we can try to go some steps further with this. From what i see in the FAQ of Discord tagged as "embed", they are willing to support what you like. I contacted them, let us see if they get back

Comment: I had a play with all options and didnt get any video running in the last 2 hous. would need some serious test setup i guess. Let me know or better write a new question if you need help using this ;-)

Comment: Hmm ok i dont understand how to do what ever is in those links you added to your original post. Also i dont know what im ment to let you know about when you said "let me know"... But if i can do it that would be cool. When you said make a new question... What am i ment to ask? i still dont know what im looking for lol... @Harry

Comment: I see now where you are coming from. You did let me know that you dont stand a chance to use any of the methods above, thats fine with me. Next question on Stack overflow would be like "how to start with...". Anyway, thats the reason why i am here, to explore yet-to-me unknown technologies. Give me some time to test and i'll update you with the results here. What i do is to try and get you some minimalistic, easy to use example. Do you own the domain  thg-graphics and do you have full access to the server? Is it running on php? Are the Videos on that server?

Comment: Your backend language is PHP? ...status update: no success with my tries, contacted support again submitting my code asking whats wrong

Comment: No. HTML and CSS is what i can write in. Not amazinly but i can write in it. PHP i have no idea how to write i google for that. IF it works geat if not then i find something that does.  So atm im in search of how to use what you linked me cos i have no idea how to implement it and reading what was on the page isnt exactly much help.. Thanks for the help @Harry. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I played around with all supported methods but didnt get video working by now. Bumbed the support email just now because didnt get response. Added easy to use examples you can experiment with in my answer

Comment: None of those links have a video on them? Besides that i dont understand any of this. The code looks right and on point but it doesnt work lol.... Thanks for the help @harry

Comment: And the final conclusion: i got invited to the dev board, asked my question there and it turns out that it will only work for certain domains, so uploading to youtube might be the best option in the end. To protect your videos there look out for wartermarking ;-) cheers!

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the help @Harry! :D I appreciate you taking the time to do that for me :D. Yes i watermark all my stuff :D