# How do I integrate an embedded player into my website's metadata?

Tags: javascript, html, css, discord

Currently, I'm using this to make a beautiful embed:

```html
<meta name="description" content="Watch non-copyrighted media online.">
<meta name="keywords" content="bruh,dev,BruhDev,memes,meme,code,developer,software,engineer,coder,code,programmer,program,develop,develope,games,media,movies,tv,shows,movie,show,series,episode,season,seasons,episodes,netflix,hbo,hulu">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFA90A">
```

And this is how it looks like on Discord:
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDz9q.png)

But this is not enough, I want to embed an entire player into this, which you can see on
http://media.bruhdev.com/media/movies/watch/3, like on Youtube: [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhDuB.png)

For the video, I use this HTML (view page source to see): http://media.bruhdev.com/media/movies/embed/3

How do I put this on the embed of my site?

*Don't mind the actual video, that's the thing about all my friends wanting their funny video's on here.

Comment: I think I already figured it out by another session of googling, and I saw meta tags have og:video, I confirmed it by looking into the code of Youtube and now I'm just waiting for Discord to update the embed.

Comment: Yeah i just saw that myself and therefore deleted my comment :D Here is the answer for anyone who find this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112759/7409991

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ahendwh2 for the answer, for anyone finding this post, here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112759/7409991