# How can I add an OG meta tag that embeds a video?

Tags: html, video, embed, meta-tags

I have been trying to embed a video in my HTML page using [OG Meta Tag](https://ogp.me/) and it does not work apparently. Here's my code:

```html
<meta property="og:video" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/urmom/nSRzP8fihY.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/urmom/nSRzP8fihY.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="500" />
```

If someone can help me, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Not obvious how _"It does not work"_. How to recreate the problem?

Comment: So when I try to paste the URL of my website in Discord, it just does not show the video at all. However, when I changed og:video to og:image and put an image URL it works, so I know that images work but videos don't.

Comment: Short version: It's not possible!!... On Discord, only [white-listed websites are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106938/how-to-add-embedded-links-to-html-5-videos#comment81707390_47112759) to display video. I remember 6-8 years ago when OG tags worked everywhere (could even use Flash video or game player in Facebook status via OG). I guess some bad guys later pissed off the system (_eg:_ copyrighted or adult material being posted via OG) so it was stopped. Youtube is still allowed as "safe" by many sites maybe because they have a system to check for such copyright material.

Answer (score 0):

it is not `og:video:secure_url`

it is `og:video:url`

so it has to be like that

```html
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/urmom/nSRzP8fihY.mp4" />
```