# How to Embed my videos to patreon to stream it?

Tags: video, video-streaming, embed, patreon

I have a creator account in Patreon.com
When I give URL from Youtube or Vimeo, it looks like this
[image: You]

but when I add URL of videos stored on my server, it looks something like this
[image]

I do not know what is the exact problem with it? If any of you faces such issue or have any idea about this then please help me.

Comment: _"I do not know what is the exact problem with it?"_ I suspect because your server is not a known and "trusted" video source. At least Youtube won't have any bad or copyrighted content. Did you try anything like use an HTTPS server or add OpenGraph `<og>` tags to the page with video? Not obvious what _"I add URL of videos"_ means, is this an HTML page url or is it an MP4 file url?

Comment: If I add HTML page with Video tag or directly add mp4 file both not working. Can you please tell me more about OpenGraph, maybe it can help.

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478860/how-can-i-add-an-og-meta-tag-that-embeds-a-video) (and the link mentioned in there) helps you to understand. Put the OG tags inside the `<head> ... </head>` section.